# Storing only ids in Redis?

Tags: redis, scalability, lookup, infrastructure

I am building a lookup service which I am expecting would receive 0.1 Million requests per second. The service would just be storing a set of ids with an expiry time(say 1 hr) and very few of these ids would be looked up before expiring and those that will be looked up would be looked up at most once. I would be deleting the keys once they are looked up.

I have a few questions surrounding this and would be nice to have answers from someone with a strong understanding of Redis

1. After due research, I am considering Redis for this task over the likes of Aerospike, Hbase, Cassandra, etc. Is Redis a good choice for this?
2. My use case only requires the ids(keys). Does it make sense to store only the ids as keys with no corresponding value. How does one do that in Redis?
3. My keys are 32 character long hexadecimals and with expiry as 1 hr and expecting 0.1 Million requests per second. I expect 2% of the keys to be looked up before expiry once and the rest will never be looked up. Is there any straight forward way to do this kind of benchmarking?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, Redis is perfectly suited for this task.
2. It also makes perfectly sense to just store the IDs in redis. As you indicated that you want to expire them on an individual basis it would be a requirement that they are separate keys (there's a solution using sorted sets, but I would not recommend that in your case). You can store just an ID via: `SET 01234567890abcdef0123456789abcdef ""` - this will create a key called "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef" and assign it an empty value. If at the same time you want to set an expiration time on the key, you would use: `SETEX 01234567890abcdef0123456789abcdef 3600 ""` - this creates the same key and expires it after one hour (3600 secs).
3. The redis-benchmark command should help here. It is installed when you installed the redis commmand line client (redis-cli). Take a look at `redis-benchmark --help` and then try to run 1000000 GET, SET tests via: `redis-benchmark -t get,set -n 1000000 -q`

**Update (after follow-on questions in comments):**

1. Unfortunately I can't tell you whether redis is the *best* solution, because that would imply that I know about every other possible solution :-) There are a lot more factors that need to be taken into account to narrow the problem space: Are there multiple clients accessing the list of IDs? Or is it only one client? Is the expiration time 1hr? Or a lot more/less? At any given time, how many IDs will exist (you only mention req/sec, but make no mention of the number of items present)?
   That said, for the projects I worked on, I found redis to be extremely fast and reliable. With my limited knowledge I would recommend redis to you as the best solution.
2. Given the data structures that redis offers, I'd say yes. If there is other data that could be useful to you instead of an empty value, you could certainly store it at the ID location without compromising performance.
3. Hmm - maybe you can play with these two: setting the keys - `redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -r 1000000 -q setex xxx:__rand_int__ 3600 ''` and retrieving keys - `redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -r 1000000 -q get xxx:__rand_int__`. Put them in a script and run one of them in the background after adjusting the values to more resemble your real problem.

Please be aware that the setex command in the benchmark will pollute the redis database: it will create a lot of xxx: keys, which you will need to dispose of (redis-cli keys xxx:* | xargs redis-cli del) - DON'T RUN THIS ON A PRODUCTION SYSTEM, BUT ONLY A TEST INSTANCE!

Comment: Thank you tobiash. I have a few follow-up questions 1. I do know that Redis is suited for this task. My question however is that is it the best choice for the given task. 2. Is storing empty values the most efficient way of going about this? 3. I am aware of Redis-benchmark but is there a way to use it to closely mimic my use-case. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking at around 4 Million ids at any given time. Each id having an expiration time of 1 hr